# Get function name and code inside function with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I am developing an application that reads and visualizes the entered codes.

```
#[account]
pub struct Tweet {
pub author: Pubkey,
pub timestamp: i64,
pub topic: String,
pub content: String,
}
```

I'm trying to get the struct name and the structures in it

```js
const stringCode = `
#[account]
pub struct Tweet {
pub author: Pubkey,
pub timestamp: i64,
pub topic: String,
pub content: String,
}
`;

const functionRegexp =
  /(pub struct\s+)(?<name>[$_\p{ID_Start}][$\u200c\u200c\p{ID_Continue}]*)/u;

const parseCode = () => {
  const match = functionRegexp.exec(stringCode);
  return parseCode;
};
```

I can see `Tweet` name in `match.groups.name`, but

```
pub author: Pubkey,
pub timestamp: i64,
pub topic: String,
pub content: String,
```

if i want to get this data? thanks!

Comment: don't use regex.  Use a lexical parser, ideally one that somebody already wrote for the language in question.  It's basically impossible to achieve something like this with a straight regex, especially for someting as complicated as code analysis and visualization.

Comment: thank you for your comment, but the application is very simple, just by visually showing the structures, it shows how much space that structure takes up in memory, not as complicated as the new code analysis.

Comment: What if the types aren't as simple? What if it's `HashMap<i32, (Option<bool>, Option<bool>)>` or some crazier type?

Comment: it won't be as detailed in my own usage, but since it will be open source other people might be disappointed, I'll think about it. Thx for your comment

Comment: It depends on what your scope is. This matches the separate strings `\b(pub \w+:?\s+)(?<name>[$_\p{ID_Start}][$\u200c\u200c\p{ID_Continue}]*)` https://regex101.com/r/6nVaHq/1 But this is not bound to `#[account]`

Comment: thanks for your comment sir, I shared the project on github(as far as I can), thanks for your support! @Thefourthbird

https://github.com/tolgaand/avss

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex to group the **struct name** and the **code** inside brackets:

```
/pub struct (\w+)|(?<= )((?:.|\s)+)(?=$)/gm
```

`pub struct (\w+)` match the struct name

`|` the **or(|)** split the expression, the second expression starts from the first one.

`(?<= )((?:.|\s)+)(?=$)` match the code inside struct. Starting from the space after the struct name`(?<= )` match all characters`((?:.|\s)+)` until reach the end of string`(?=$)`.

Answer (score 0):

This will parse and return the name and the data structure:

```js
const stringCode = `
#[account]
pub struct Tweet {
pub author: Pubkey,
pub timestamp: i64,
pub topic: String,
pub content: String,
}
`;

const functionRegexp =
  /\bpub\s+struct\s+([$_\p{ID_Start}][$\u200c\u200c\p{ID_Continue}]*)\s*\{\s*([^\{]*?)\s*\}/u;

const match = functionRegexp.exec(stringCode);
console.log('name: ' + match[1]);
console.log('data:\n' + match[2]);
```

Output:

```
name: Tweet
data:
pub author: Pubkey,
pub timestamp: i64,
pub topic: String,
pub content: String,
```

Explanation:

- `\bpub\s+struct\s+` - expect `pub struct` with word boundary
- `([$_\p{ID_Start}][$\u200c\u200c\p{ID_Continue}]*)` - capture group 1 for name
- `\s*\{\s*` - expect optional whitespace, `{`, optional whitespace
- `([^\{]*?)` - capture group 2 for data: anything non-greedily that is not `{`
- `\s*\}` - expect optional whitespace and `}`